# Typescript Vuex - How to define a state with a setter and getter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

In the vuex store I want to initialize a state called _token. When I'm trying to access the property within the same class, it gives me the error message that the setter for _token is not defined. Anyone has an idea why only the getter is available?

```
export default class Api extends VuexModule {
  public _token = '';

  @Action
  public async [VuexActionsApi.VerifyUser](data: any): Promise<IResponseState> {
    const vuexInstance = this;

    // this is not working
    vuexInstance._token = "test";
}
```

[image: log output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work now, when i defined the state like this:

```
public data = {
  bearerToken: undefined
};
```

Now the setter and getter functions are created correctly. Someone has an idea why the first approach didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use class decorators then you must import them (and install the package) like this:

```
import Action from 'vue-class-component'
```

Although I might advise against that syntax as it is being deprecated in vue3, see here:
https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/17#issuecomment-494242121

Comment: I imported the class decorator from the package
"import { Action, Module, VuexModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators';"

Is also this package deprecated with vue3? Which alternative do you suggest?

Comment: No that's fine, it just won't be officially supported in vue3 (you should still be able to use the package.

Comment: So there is no official typescript vue support? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have now seen that the typescript decorator will be build into Vue 3.0. So my question above is not relevant anymore :)